# Trying to end code execution in an express js route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

currently I have a simple express route with nodejs. If a certain condition is met in a mongoDB query i want to redirect the user and stop any further code from executing.

Some things I have already tried:
- return
- res.end()

An example of code is below

```
router.post("/test",  (req, res) => {
    Col.findOne({ 'val': req.body.val })
    .then(val => {
        if (val) {
            // 1st attempt
            return res.redirect("/testing");
            //2nd attempt
            res.redirect("/testing");
            res.end();
            // 3rd attempt
            res.redirect("/testing");
            return;
        }
    })
    console.log("Do NOT want this to execute but it does anyways");

}));
```

The issue is that after the code in the (if) statement executes and returns / res.end(), the code outside the .then() still executes

Comment: Did it work or still having any issues ? Also in addition to my answer please try to close DB connection as required..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Async/await in Express](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/)

```js
router.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
  const val = await Col.findOne({val: req.body.val});
  if (val) {
    res.redirect("/testing");
  } else {
    // other code goes here
  }
}));
```

Comment: I am using promises, plus my question is about exiting the route and finishing code execution, not about mongodb syntax

Comment: What code is being executed? In the example, there is no other code other than in callback

Comment: Just updated the code, async wasnt in the route anyways my mistake

Comment: I do not understand. You have an asynchronous function that runs asynchronously as a callback. And you also have a synchronous code on this route that you don't want to be executed. Then remove it. If you want this code to execute when `!!val === false` then add it to the `else` block. If you run something asynchronously, don't expect the synchronous code to wait for the result.

Comment: Please check my updated code, it is no longer an async function. I am using promises with mongodb, not callbacks.

Comment: Querying the database returns Promise (I think) and I could not find a solution that would launch Promise synchronously. So when this condition is met from the database, you redirect, otherwise you execute the code from the else block. I don't see any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

On mongoDB `.findOne` would return `null` if it didn't find any matching document as per given filter query. In case of falsy values then you need to have `else` block in order to get out of execution(Here you actually got a proper response from DB not an error - but it might be a falsy value `null`). Please add `.catch()` block as well for any errors.

```
router.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    Col.findOne({ 'val': req.body.val })
        .then(val => {
            if (val) {
                return res.redirect("/testing");
            } else {
                return res.send('No val found')
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('In Err ::', err)
            return res.send('Some error occurred')
        })
})
```